# Solving set of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the set

$dx/dt = cos(\theta) $

$dy/dt = sin(\theta) $

$d\theta/dt = - cos(\theta) $

How is the way to start solving these equations.

Thanks

Comment: Start with the observation that $x+\theta$ is a constant.

Comment: Is $\theta$ dependent on $t$ here ?

Comment: @FareedAF: This is implied. If it wasn't, the other two ODEs for $x$ and $y$ would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You solve the last equation with separation, using some method for rational expressions in trigonometric functions. Or here easier, using trigonometric identities
$$
-t+c=\int\frac{\cosθ \,dθ}{1-\sin^2θ}=\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}=\frac12\ln|1-u|-\frac12\ln|1+u|\\
Ce^{-2t}=\frac{1-\sinθ}{1+\sinθ}=\tan^2\left(\fracθ2-\frac\pi4\right)
$$
so that with $C=A^2$
$$
θ(t)=\frac\pi2+2\arctan(Ae^{-t})\\
\sinθ=\frac{1-A^2e^{-2t}}{1+A^2e^{-2t}}=\frac{e^t-A^2e^{-t}}{e^t+A^2e^{-t}}
$$

Then use, as already mentioned, $x-θ=B=const.$ and integrate the expression you get by isolating $\sinθ$ to get $y$,
$$
y(t)=\ln(e^t+A^2e^{-t})+D=t+D+\ln(1+A^2e^{-2t})
$$
The constants are determined by the initial conditions
$$
A=e^{t_0}\tan\left(\frac{θ_0}2-\frac\pi4\right)
\\
B=x_0-θ_0
\\
D=y_0-t_0-\ln(1+A^2e^{-2t_0})
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, years that I didn't solve things like this, can you please give me a few more details of the answer. Thanks